# Is it legal to use bitcoin in a domain name?

Tags: legal, domain-registering

Is it legal to use bitcoin in a domain name? Not a sub domain, but in the main domain name.

Comment: What do you mean 'in' a domain name? A domain name which contains the substring 'bitcoin'? Buying a domain name with bitcoin? Putting a bitcoin address on a website?

Comment: @PieterWuille like bitcoinShop.com so the main domain name has the word bitcoin in it not a subdomain like bitcoin.example.com

Comment: Why would that be illegal? Is is not allowed to have a website with the name dollar in it?

Comment: @PieterWuille just wanted to make sure cause its based on MIT license and opensource but the name it self might be registered for some reason. Thanks for your help Pieter :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To date, no entity has trademarked word "Bitcoin" in the US.** This means that it's highly unlikely that any US entity would file against your domains under the [ICANN Uniform Domain-Name Dispute-Resolution Policy](http://www.icann.org/en/help/dndr/udrp).

There was a [servicemark application for Bitcoin](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4010:2umkik.2.5), but it was abandoned in July 2011.

#### Related trademark applications

- Bitpay applied for [Merchant Solutions for the bitcoin currency](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4010:2umkik.2.4) and [Bitcoin Merchant Solutions](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4010:2umkik.2.3), both also abandoned.
- There is one for [Bitcoin appliance](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4010:2umkik.2.2), also abandoned.
- [Bitcoin Magazine](http://tess2.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4010:2umkik.2.1) applied for a trademark, and it's still in processing.

Comment: Mt. Gox registered it. https://mtgox.com/press_release_20111014.html http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=128254.msg1365911#msg1365911